# Undefined procedure in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog

Ok i got these two predicated `hangman` and `graphics`

```
fail([]).

hangman:-
    getPhrase(Ans), 
    !, 
    write('Welcome to hangman.'),
    nl,
    fail(FailedList), 
    graphics(FailedList), %<--- The call is made here.
    name(Ans,AnsList), 
    makeBlanks(AnsList, BlankList),
    getGuess(AnsList,BlankList, FailedList).


graphics(FailedList):-
    length(FailedList, L),
    L == 0,
    write('-----------'), nl,
    write('|'), nl,
    write('|'), nl,
    write('|'), nl,
    write('|'), nl,
    write('|'), nl,
    write('|'), nl,
    write('|'), nl,
    write('|'), nl,
    write('/\'), nl.
```

Why do i get the error: `ERROR: hangman/0: Undefined procedure: graphics/1`?
Note that if i put the predicate `graphics` inside `hangman` in comments my program works fine.

Comment: you forgot the closing `'` in your `write/1` statements.

Comment: @Mog Thanks for your help but i still get the error. Any ideas of why it doesn't recognize it?

Comment: @Mog you have the credits for the answer, mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 write('/\'), nl.
```

In the last line, you are escaping the ending quotation mark with `\'`. Change it to:

```
 write('/\\'), nl.
```

BTW: @Mog has written the answer before I had a look at the comments, I tested it and now it finds graphics/1.

Answer (score 3):

(this answer is not really about the question asked so please let the answer to @SeçkinSavaşçı who did a great job answering the question, it's more of a code review)

Here, you visibly want to test if a list is empty and react accordingly by displaying some things. For the test if a list is empty part, you're doing it wrong:

```
graphics(FailedList):-
    length(FailedList, L),
    L == 0,
    % some IO stuff
```

In prolog, you can use unification in a more straightforward manner:

```
graphics(FailedList):-
    length(FailedList, 0),
    % some IO stuff
```

or, better, where you directly test for the empty list in the head as a condition to execute the body of the predicate:

```
graphics([]):-
    % some IO stuff
```

For the IO part, you're doing it kinda wrong again. SWI-Prolog, for example, has a `writeln/1` predicate, that would make your code lighter:

```
graphics([]):-
    writeln('-----------'),
    writeln('|'),
    writeln('|'),
    writeln('|'),
    writeln('|'),
    writeln('|'),
    writeln('|'),
    writeln('|'),
    writeln('|'),
    writeln('/\\').
```

Still better, the `format/1` predicate could be used:

```
graphics([]):-
    format('-----------~n|~18~n|~n|~n|~n|~n|~n|~n|~n/\\').
```

The main predicate seems to have some problems too, but I'll let you look into it and ask questions if you're stuck somewhere :)

Comment: great overview for the general improvement of the implementation.